# upload folder Dicom with orthanc library

Tags: javascript, php, dicom

I want upload file DICOM and index all dcm files with orthanc Library.
I write this code:

```
php:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $url="http://localhost:8042/instances";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
text/plain'));
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $i => $name) {
        curl_setopt($ch, 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,file_get_contents($name));
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($result);   
    }
}

html:
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple="" directory="" 
     webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

this code takes long time so mush..
what is problem ??
I want method to upload directory of dcm files and index its togother with API orthanc and using php, js..

thank you..

Comment: Hello, I took the opportunity to post a generic solution to uploading a specific set of files from a server or personal computer.

Were you looking to upload a specific set of files or are you trying to build a solution that allows users to specify the set of files they want?  If the latter, you should probably not be sending your files to a php server, as hinted in the alternatives section of my answer, the ideal solution includes sending the files directly from the browser to the orthanc server through the dicomweb protocol. If anyone is interested in such an answer, let me know.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the robust [store scu](https://book.orthanc-server.com/users/cookbook.html) function of any DICOM compliant client. The most popular of which is dcmtk.

```
 storescu -aec ORTHANC localhost 4242 *.dcm
```

You can find installation instructions for the dcmtk package [on this link](https://dcmtk.org/dcmtk.php.en) and documentation for storescu [on this link](https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/storescu.html)

### Command breakdown

> storescu

Is the name of the store scu function of the dcmtk package.

> -aec ORTHANC

Specifies the AE title of the server, it should match the aet as it was configured in orthanc, ORTHANC is the default. Depending on the Orthanc version and configuration, it might not even be necessary to specify the the -aec parameter. But the documentation recommends this regardless.

> specifies the address of the server. If it's running on the same computer it's probably localhost.
>
> 4242

4242 is the default port of the orthanc server for DICOM connections. If you changed this either through orthanc configuration, or other port redirection mechanism (like docker's) you should specify so.

> *.dcm

The asterisk means that all files that match this pattern should be uploaded. storescu will look for the files in the folder where it was executed from. If you are having trouble here, just specify the full path as such /orthanc/ct/*.dcm or C:\orthanc\ct*.dcm

### Running programatically

If you need to upload files specific files to test or view a CT, then you probably don't need to run this from a programming language, you can run it manually from the shell.
If you really need to run the script programatically and a .sh or .bat script won't do you can execute this command from your programming language of choice

In php it would be something like this:

> $success_or_error = shell_exec("storescu -aec ORTHANC localhost 4242 *.dcm")

Or in Python

> import subprocess
> subprocess.run(["storescu", "-aec" , "ORTHANC", "localhost", "4242", "*.dcm"])

### Alternatives

I do not recommend these alternatives but I feel compelled to list them for completeness sake.

If you are looking for an open source but inferior alternative you can try gdcm's gdcmstore (installation instructions [here](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Downloads), documentation available through gdcmscu --help and man gdcmscu)

Orthanc offers also offers the possibility to upload files through their Orhtanc specific API (mostly for historic reasons I believe) or their DICOM compliant DICOMweb api. To do so one would need to use any http client such as curl or python's requests. If you are looking to upload files from a webbrowser, a dicomweb solution from a js http client is probably the best idea.

Comment: Another alternative, one that I could actually recommend, is "dcmsend" from the DCMTK. This tool is smarter than storescu by only proposing those presentation contexts (i.e. combination of SOP Class and Transfer Syntaxes) that are actually needed for the DICOM files (datasets) to be transferred.

Comment: "In contrast to the well-known storescu utility, dcmsend has  less  options  and  is, therefore,  easier  to  use" 
Interesting, thanks for the suggestion, feel free to edit my answer and replace storescu with dcmsend, it's similar enough that it should go in the main body, not the alternatives. You should probably still keep a reference to storescu for SEO purposes, but not necessarily explain the differences as to not burden the reader.

Comment: @Tomas Zubiri  Seems like you know a bit about Orthanc ?  Offline, or another question, but is it possible to build a Modality worklist server in PHP as part of an EMR ?  I build a PHP class that can build an .wl file using dump2dcm from dcmtk, but I would like to listen to acquisition device and send back .wl 's.  If that is possible, would not be too hard to build a RIS / EMR.

Comment: Feel free to post it as a stackoverflow question and I'll try to check it out. It's kind of hard to communicate otherwise. Having the conversation here would get it flagged as off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fill your POST in the following style:

```
$cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
$post = array('file_contents'=> $cFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

Something like this. So first use `curl_file_create` and then put them in the POST and then you can put that to the post fields.